# mocha access variable in file which function i test

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, sinon

Okay i will try to explain this simple. So i have this file that has this variable and then the function i am testing

```
let config: Config|undefined;

export default async function onConfigEvent(event: myEvent) {

  if (isDefined(config)) {
    console.log('Ignoring config event because we already have the config.');
    return;
  }

  config = event.config as Config;

  if (!config.firstThing) {
    console.log('config miss first thing.')
    return;
  }

  if (!config.otherthing) {
    console.log('config missing second thing.');
    return;
  }
}
```

Then i try to test these two negative if like this

```
describe('OnConfigEvent', () => {

  it('should log missing second thing', () => {

    let event: ConfigEvent = {
      type: events.Config,
      config: { ["firstThing"]: false }
    }

    let spy = sinon.spy(console, 'log');

    onConfigEvent(event)

    assert(spy.calledWith('Missing first thing.'));

    spy.restore();
  });

  it('should log missing second thing', () => {

    let event: ConfigEvent = {
      type: events.Config,
      config: { ["firstThing"]: true }
    }
    let spy = sinon.spy(console, 'log');

    onConfigEvent(event)

    assert(spy.calledWith('config missing second thing.'));

    spy.restore();
  });
});
```

Problem here is that after first test has been run the second one will return the first if statement `"Ignoring config event because we already have the config."` as the config gets set during the first test. How do i access the `let gameConfig` from the file i am testing a function in. so i can set it to undefined before every test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) to reset the value of `config` variable.

`index.ts`:

```js
type Config = any;
type myEvent = any;
let config: Config | undefined;

function isDefined(obj) {
  return obj !== undefined;
}

export default function onConfigEvent(event: myEvent) {
  if (isDefined(config)) {
    console.log('Ignoring config event because we already have the config.');
    return;
  }

  config = event.config as Config;

  if (!config.firstThing) {
    console.log('config miss first thing.');
    return;
  }

  if (!config.otherthing) {
    console.log('config missing second thing.');
    return;
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { assert } from 'chai';
import rewire from 'rewire';
type ConfigEvent = any;
const events = { Config: 'Config' };

describe('OnConfigEvent', () => {
  let onConfigEvent;
  let mod;
  beforeEach(() => {
    mod = rewire('./');
    onConfigEvent = mod.default;
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    mod.__set__({ config: undefined });
  });
  it('should log missing first thing', () => {
    let event: ConfigEvent = {
      type: events.Config,
      config: { ['firstThing']: false },
    };
    let spy = sinon.spy(console, 'log');
    onConfigEvent(event);
    assert(spy.calledWith('config miss first thing.'));
    spy.restore();
  });

  it('should log missing second thing', () => {
    let event: ConfigEvent = {
      type: events.Config,
      config: { ['firstThing']: true },
    };
    let spy = sinon.spy(console, 'log');
    onConfigEvent(event);
    assert(spy.calledWith('config missing second thing.'));
    spy.restore();
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
  OnConfigEvent
config miss first thing.
    ✓ should log missing first thing
config missing second thing.
    ✓ should log missing second thing


  2 passing (1s)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   83.33 |    66.67 |     100 |   83.33 |                   
 index.ts |   83.33 |    66.67 |     100 |   83.33 | 11,12             
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```